# How to fix bootstrap carousel with multiple images?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel, responsive

Here is my carousel. I need create slider with multiple images. It has to be something like netflix carousel.

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators d-none">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4">

                   <img src="img/10.jpg" class="img-item" alt="...">


            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">

                <img src="img/11.jpg" class="img-item" alt="...">


         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">

            <img src="img/12.jpg" class="img-item" alt="...">


          </div>

         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I wrapped imgs inside col and embeded them in one row.
Actually, all the pics are displayed ok but slider does not work!

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the JS for bootstrap in your documents head?

```
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Other than that it should work. But if still doesn't have a look at this example and compare it to yours:
[Carousel Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2)